# Button created dynamically cant accses

Tags: javascript

I am learning javascript, and i am trying to get accses to a button that is created dynamically within a function. The first function createHtml just gets data and creates elements and store them in a variable that i add to the html element and store them in the beerContainer, and that works. I cant however accses the button that is created in the function createHtml. How can i get the alert to pop up when im clicking on saveBeer?

```
 let btn = document.querySelector('#myBtn');
    let beerContainer = document.querySelector('#beer-data');

            function createHtml(result) {
            
              var html = '';
              for(let i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
               
              
                html +=  "<h3>"+ result.data[i].name +"</h3>"
                html +=  "<p>"+ result.data[i].description +"</p>"
                html += "<button id='save-beer' data-id='"+ result.data[i].id+"'>Save Beer</button>"
            
              }
              beerContainer.innerHTML = html;
            }
            
            
            btn.addEventListener('click', function(event) { 
              fetchApiData(createHtml);
            });

var saveBeer = document.querySelector('.save-beer');

saveBeer.addEventListener('click', function(event) { 
 alert("Hi");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
    var saveBeer = document.querySelector('#save-beer'); // access by id
```

rather than

```
   var saveBeer = document.querySelector('.save-beer'); // trying to access by class which does not exist
```

Note the '#' rather than '.' in the querySelector argument